# Can telegram bot access recent action from telegram supergroup?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

So i would like to make a bot that can access recent action from my supergroup. The flow is pretty simple, i want the bot to scrape all of the information inside of it and save it into database. I made it with python and telegram bot API

The bot is already admin and he can do anything that admin could do.

Is it possible to do that???

Answer (score 1):

No. Bots can only do what's listed in the official API docs at https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. Instead, you can just keep track of what's happening in the chat.

Comment: So, if i just want to scrape information from recent action. Is there any tools or something that can help me?

Comment: It's probably possible via a userbot. My point is that you'd have to do the scraping in regular intervals to get all the info and then try to figure out which parts you have already saved and which parts are new. So instead of doing that, you could just listen to all events happening in the chat and save them

Comment: Is userbot can detect all the events inside supergroup?? I wondering is there any tools or solution that can detect/save automatically when any user joined to my group knowing that the notification message (joined message) in supergroup is dissapeared.

Comment: a user bot automates your normal telegram account, so it can see everything that you have access to. to keep track of users joining/leaving a group, a bot suffices. See the `chat_member` field of [`Update`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update)

Comment: "you can just keep track of what's happening in the chat" - except you can't, because for some actions there are no updates sent to the bot whatsoever. For example, if a message that the bot can see gets deleted, there's no way for the bot to know via the API (even if the bot is an admin), neither in real time nor by polling. It's actually a huge flaw of the API. (I mean the Bot API, not the MTProto API which is designed for creating client apps and completely unusable for writing bots).